# VB.net reading ASCII code while reading a text file

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am reading a text file in VB.net code. I want to read this line that contains some special character that has a dec value of 176 and hex value is B1 and symbol is + and - at the botttom. Below is the URL that shows that value:

```
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm
```

How can I read that special character in VB.net that has value of 176

The line is like this

```
"2314 Test1  Test2 Test3 12.3 special character that has a Dec value of 176 1234"
```

each word is separated by a tab.

This is what I did so far:

```
     reader = File.OpenText(fileInfo.FullName)
    While reader.Peek <> -1

     line = reader.ReadLine()
   End While
   reader.Close()
  reader.Dispose()
```

I also tried to do this:

```
 System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(line)
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could show us what you have done so far (and the dec value of the sign you're referring to is 177)

Comment: Well you read the file with the appropriate encoding. Do you know what encoding it is? (It's not ASCII. ASCII doesn't contain that character. The site you're looking at is misleading you.)

Comment: I modified my post with what I did so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx) of the `StreamReader` class (from the `System.IO` namespace):

```
Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\Users\trashr0x\Desktop\test.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
End Using
```

You can also use the [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369.aspx) method (again, from `System.IO`):

```
Dim testString as String = File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\trashr0x\Desktop\test.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
```

I've set the encoding to `Encoding.Unicode`. If you don't know the encoding of your file, you can try the other values:

- `Encoding.ASCII` (As @Jon Skeet pointed out in the comments of your question, this symbol is not ASCII)
- `Encoding.UTF32`
- `Encoding.UTF8`
- `Encoding.UTF7`
- `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`
- `Encoding.Default` (the default encoding is ANSI)

An interesting read as an aside: ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky.